# open with explorer in document library

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, document-library, open-with-explorer

I have a document library with 2 folders, I tried to use the **open with explorer** I can see both folders , I can't find all the files in one of the folders! the **folder empty**

How can I copy all the files to my PC from document library ? !!

Comment: Which permissions do you have when doing this action ?

Comment: Is that Document Library contains more that 2000 items..? check this once https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88655/document-library-open-with-explorer-shows-empty-folder-sharepoint-2010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with @TARUN. Also, you should be aware of the `List\Doc Library view threshold` for SharePoint 2013 is **5000 items**. for more details check [Software boundaries and limits for SharePoint 2013](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262787.aspx#ListLibrary)

**What's this mean?**

First, let's define `Threshold`

**Threshold:** is a Configurable limit that can be exceeded to accommodate specific requirements.

There are three main ways to work with the List View Threshold:

- For all versions of SharePoint, manage the number of items returned using indexing, filtering, folders, and offline data.
- For Server versions of SharePoint, use an administrator scheduled Daily Time Window where limits are raised.
- For Server versions of SharePoint, a network administrator can raise the limit of the List View Threshold.

For more details check [Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59?ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&fromAR=1)

**Regarding How can I copy all the files to my PC from document library? !!**

I suggest checking a great free tool called [SPFileZilla](https://spfilezilla.codeplex.com/) that may help. It allows for you to Browse site lists, document libraries, folders, and files. Download and upload files and folders, including support for nested folders hierarchies.

[image]

Once you [download](https://spfilezilla.codeplex.com/releases/view/115141) the tool, you will find a config file, Open it to set the **row limit** of your files that will be downloaded.

Answer (score 2):

> It is not recommended to exceed 2,000 items in a list level, and to
>   use Explorer view to view large document libraries. Instead, you may
>   choose to use All Document view, when open a SharePoint document
>   library in Explorer view, placing the pointer over any of the
>   enumerated files requests metadata for all of the files in the folder
>   that you are browsing.
>
> As in this scenario, it may be the large number of the documents that
>   make the Explorer View not working, here is an article about “Tune Web
>   Server performance(Office SharePoint Server)”, there are some points
>   we need to pay attention to in “Train end-users to work with large
>   files”, for more information, please refer to:
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc298550(office.12).aspx

[Document library Open with Explorer ; shows empty folder - SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88655/document-library-open-with-explorer-shows-empty-folder-sharepoint-2010)

Comment: agree! but i  want to  copy all the files to my PC from document library , How? !!!