# Files are not showing when i mapped Library locally for particular folders

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, open-with-explorer, network-drive

I have mapped a SharePoint document library to Local PC using the option "Add Network Location".

One of the folder in the Library has 9000 PDF files. When I go to the web mode I am able to see the PDF files, but when I tried to view the same PDF files using Windows Explorer it is not showing files, instead showing an error: "The Folder is Empty".

I have attached the image.

Is this the expected behavior due to 9 K files in the folder?

Please suggest

[image]

Comment: Is it showing the documents in windows explorer if the files are less than 5000? Try it on newly created document library with 4-5 documents on same site? Also try adding this site in trusted sites and connecting your sharepoint site on internet explorer. [Add your SharePoint Online sites to trusted sites](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/support/administration/troubleshoot-mapped-network-drives#add-your-sharepoint-online-sites-to-trusted-sites).

Answer (score 1):

It is not recommended to exceed 2,000 items in a library level, and to use Explorer view to view large document libraries.

For more information you can check below similar questions asked by community:

1. [open with explorer in document library](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/216323/open-with-explorer-in-document-library)
2. [Document library Open with Explorer ; shows empty folder - SharePoint 2010](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/88655/document-library-open-with-explorer-shows-empty-folder-sharepoint-2010)

You can manage your large lists/libraries by creating folders or indexing columns. For more information check below article:

[Manage large lists and libraries in SharePoint](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-large-lists-and-libraries-in-SharePoint-b8588dae-9387-48c2-9248-c24122f07c59).

Comment: Does this answers your question?